# How to add incremental value base on a column?

Tags: r

For example, how do I obtain the value for the column "rank"?
Here, the value increases by every 2 records in the data frame. Thought it could be any # of records instead of 2.

I did found a few similar posts, but they are not exactly what I need.

| Months | rank |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 8 | 4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rep` and `each=` argument according to `nrow(dat)/n`.

```
f <- \(dat, n) {
  stopifnot(nrow(dat) %% n == 0)  ## for safety
  rep(seq_len(nrow(dat)/n), each=n)
}

f(dat, 1)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

f(dat, 2)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4

f(dat, 3)
# Error in f(dat, 3) : nrow(dat)%%n == 0 is not TRUE

f(dat, 4)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2

f(dat, nrow(dat))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

To also get unequal groups, you could implement an `override=` option.

```
f2 <- \(dat, n, override=FALSE) {
  if (!override) {
    stopifnot(nrow(dat) %% n == 0)
    rep(seq_len(nrow(dat)/n), each=n)
  } else {
    rep(seq_len(nrow(dat)), each=n)[seq_len(nrow(dat))]
  }
}

f2(dat, 3, override=TRUE)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3
```

Or, slightly more elegant:

```
f3 <- \(dat, n) {
  sort.int(rep_len(1:n, nrow(dat)))
}

f3(dat, 0)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1

f3(dat, 1)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

f3(dat, 2)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2

f3(dat, 3)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3

f3(dat, 8)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

f3(dat, 9)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

f3(dat, -1)
# [1] -1 -1  0  0  0  1  1  1
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Months = 1:8, rank = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: This is great. For "3", I think it will be better to have a way to handle it. like continuing to assign "7,8" as rank "3".

Comment: Ts a lot. Will run  some tests myself now. :)

Answer (score 1):

For suppose we have a data as below

```r
  letters 
1       A 
2       B 
3       C 
4       D 
5       E 
6       F 
7       G 
8       H
```

Then we do something as below

```r
df <- data.frame(letters=c(LETTERS[1:8]), Months=c(1:8)) %>% 
  mutate(rank1=(Months %% 2), 
         rank2=ifelse(rank1==1,Months, NA_real_)) %>% 
  fill(rank2) %>% 
  mutate(rank=data.table::rleid(rank2)) %>% 
  select(-c('rank1','rank2'))  

# output
  letters Months rank
1       A      1    1
2       B      2    1
3       C      3    2
4       D      4    2
5       E      5    3
6       F      6    3
7       G      7    4
8       H      8    4
```

Comment: Nice. it is always interesting to see a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code,

```r
df <- data.frame(Months=c(1:8)) %>% mutate(rank1=(Months %% 2), 
                                     rank2=ifelse(rank1==1,Months, NA_real_),
                                     ) %>% fill(rank2) %>% 
  mutate(rank=data.table::rleid(rank2)) %>% select(-c('rank1','rank2'))

# output
  Months rank
1      1    1
2      2    1
3      3    2
4      4    2
5      5    3
6      6    3
7      7    4
8      8    4
```

Comment: This is a great one as well. However, like I mentioned, the ranking should be based on the # of records, regardless of how many columns or types of data in the data frame. So, what if the column "months" here is not not numeric values, or the values are not consistent ? :)

Comment: I added another answer, please check.